# How to make the window created in VSCODE (python language) stop closing once the loop stops?

Tags: python

```
def histogram_construction():
    the_window = GraphWin("The Histogram", 500, 500)
    aRectangle = Rectangle(Point(1,3), Point(4,7))

    aRectangle.draw(the_window)
    the_window.close
```

```
def main():
    var_running = True

    while var_running:
        var_range = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]
        try:
            pass_credits = int(input("Please enter your number of credits to PASS: "))
            if pass_credits not in var_range:
                print(f"Pass credit index out of range.\n")
                continue
            defer_credits = int(input("Please enter your number of credits to DEFER: "))
            if defer_credits not in var_range:
                print(f"Defer credit index out of range.\n")
                continue
            fail_credits = int(input("Please enter your number of credits to FAIL: "))
            if fail_credits not in var_range:
                print(f"Fail credit index out of range.\n")
                continue

        except ValueError:
            print(f"Integer Required.\n")
            continue

        total_result = progression_calculation(pass_credits, defer_credits, fail_credits)

        print("Would you like to enter another student? Press 'c' for continue and 'q' for quit: ", end='')
        var_choice = input()
        var_choice = var_choice.lower()
        if var_choice == 'q':
            var_running = False
        else:
            continue

    histogram_construction()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem above is with the `histogram_construction()` function. Whenever I try to run it once the `var_running` is set to False, it automatically closes the window that gets created as well. I've tried it on Idle and it works perfectly fine there but for some reason, it doesn't work on Vscode. Assistance would be appreciated.

I tried messing with the indentation, replacing some lines of code and whatnot, but those never worked out. I decided to put it into IDLE and lord and behold, it worked without a problem yet when ran on Vscode, it didn't work.

What i'm expecting is once the user enters `q`, the function runs and a window is created until the user closes it.

Comment: Your program exiting is _supposed_ to close all its windows, and finishing your main function (or whatever other entrypoint your program is invoked at) is _supposed_ to make your program exit. So what you describe as behavior you see in VS Code is 100% normal. What's curious to me (albeit as someone who hasn't used IDLE in the better part of 20 years) is why you'd ever see anything else when using different tools.

Comment: BTW, most GUI frameworks have an explicit call you can make to pass control to a "main loop" that just handles GUI-related events; typically, you want to have your `main` explicitly hand control off to that loop instead of exiting.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the clarification! I'm unsure why, perhaps it has something to do with the the graphics.py that im importing from. However, it's not a terribly big deal due to this being for a school project which wants it ran in IDLE but I much prefer VScode so It would be good if it worked there.

But regardless, thank you for your input

Comment: I'll also point out that your histogramConstruction function also has this line `the_window.close` which currently does nothing, but if you put `()` at the end of it, then that line would be closing the window.

Comment: Is that graphics.py publicly available? We might be able to speak to things a little better after reviewing it (f/e, if it has a main-loop function, or backends into a library that provides one, we could concretely tell you what to call).